# Why does git show filename display a diff?

Tags: git, git-show

`git show filename` diplays a diff, while
`git show branch:path/to/filename` displays the content of the file.

I look in the help (`git show --help`) and what I understood is that it should
default to HEAD, i.e. `git show HEAD:filename`.

But that produces the content of the file as I expected. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Just a guess but is it perhaps showing the current version of the file in local fs with uncommitted changes and since there was a merge conflict it spliced the 2 versions of the file and is waiting for you to resolve said merge conflict? Check it with any other text editor.

Comment: Everything is clean and I do not have any merges.
My question is very general, `git show` just acts this way and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git show <path>` is equivalent to `git show HEAD <path>`.

Without `<path>`, it prints the log message and the diff of changed files of the head commit.

With `<path>`, it prints the log message and the diff of the specified path of the head commit if the file is changed in the commit. If not, nothing is printed.

Comment: You are correct. But `git show HEAD:path/to/file` will display the content of the file.
What is the difference between `HEAD file` and `HEAD:path/to/file`?

Comment: @odCat It refers to a blob object here. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememmasterREADMEem

Comment: I think I got it: `git show HEAD file` will compare HEAD with file, while `git show HEAD:path/to/file` will operate only on the file and display its content.

Answer (score 6):

I was surprised, by reading [git help show](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show), to see no mention of extra `[<path>...]` arguments. The description mentions `git diff-tree`, and although [git help diff-tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree) mentions the existence of `[<path>...]`, there is no description of what it does.
This is (IMHO) clearly a shortcoming in `git help show`.

Nevertheless, much like [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-ltpathgt82308203) or [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ltpathgt82308203), `git show <object>...` can be extended to `git show <object>... [<path>...]`, or the non ambiguous `git show <object>... -- <path>...`, which applies on commit objects to narrow what is displayed from these commits. Specifying `<path>...` has no effect on `git show` when displaying a tree or a blob.

A point that *is* mentioned in the doc is that when naming a directory (a tree), only the content of that directory is shown (not a diff), and when naming a file (a blob), only the content of that file is shown (also not a diff).

Naming such things is described in [`git help gitrevision`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) :

```
# some ways to name a tree:
git show <commit>:path/to/dir  # path from the top-level
git show <commit>:./dir  # path relative to your pwd
git show <commit>:   # the top-level of your repo at <commit>
git show <commit>^{tree}

# some ways to name a blob:
git show <commit>:full/path/to/file
git show <commit>:./rel/path/to/file
```

---

One an extra piece of information which, to my knowledge, isn't entirely worded in git doc:

for commands such as `git diff`, `git log`, `git show` tries to guess, from the names you pass on the command line, what is an object and what is a filtering path.

Meaning: when you type `git show foo/bar`

1. if `foo/bar` happens to match a branch or a tag name, it will display that object (and its diff...), and not resort to the default `HEAD`
2. if `foo/bar` matches no branch or tag but matches a path on disk, it will try to treat it as a filtering path on the default `HEAD` commit, as in `git show HEAD foo/bar` ; this will show a diff, narrowed to path `foo/bar`
3. if the string actually contains a `:`, as in `git show foo:bar` or `git show :foo/bar`, `git` will unambiguously treat this as a blob or tree name (with `foo:bar`: object located at `bar` within commit `foo`, with `:foo/bar`, object located at `foo/bar` within the default `HEAD` commit) ; this will display the plain content, and no diff

You can remove the guesswork by putting a `--` in your command line:

```
#  left of '--' : object names ('foo' and 'bar')
# right of '--' : filtering paths  ('baz' and 'buzz')
git show foo bar -- baz buzz
```

If you don't provide a `--` in your command line, and a name can be ambiguous, you would see an error message looking like that:

```
# with a file named 'master' on disk:
$ git show master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

---

Back to the OP's question :

- his first `git show filename` falls in point 2. above,
- his second `git show HEAD:path/to/filename` falls in point 3.

As stated in point 2., the only (small but impactful) thing to correct in the OP's question is that `git show filename` defaults to `git show HEAD -- filename`, not to `git show HEAD:filename`.

Comment: “This manual page describes only the most frequently used options.” Dunno why that is.

Comment: *edit* fixed an incorrection about `<path>...` applying to trees: they seem to currently be completely ignored. `git show HEAD:that/dir -- file1 file2` displays the whole content of `that/dir`, unlike `git ls-tree HEAD:that/dir -- file1 file2` which would narrow the "ls" to only those 2 paths (if they are present in said tree)

Comment: As described in my answer, providing both a commit and a path doesn't just limit what is included from that commit, it limits the actual "list" of commits to consider in the first place. That's why `git show some_commit_ref -- some_path_not_changed_in_that_commit` gives a completely empty output, not a commit header with no diff underneath.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

- `git show example.txt` means `git show HEAD -- example.txt`
- The object shown is `HEAD`, not `example.txt`
- The `example.txt` argument is used to first filter the "list" of revisions, and then filter the diff displayed
- So the result is either empty (if `example.txt` was not changed in the latest commit), or a summary of the latest commit with everything other than `example.txt` ignored

---

To figure this out, I [went to the source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2807bd2c10606e590886543afe4e4f208dddd489/builtin/log.c). It turns out that `git show` actually shares a lot of its implementation with `git log`, including how it processes its command-line arguments.

That means the synopsis from [the `git log` manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) can give us some clues:

```
git log [<options>] [<revision-range>] [[--] <path>…​]
```

Note that the revision range and path are *both* optional, and the `--` is only needed if it's ambiguous which is meant. Under [`<revision-range>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-ltrevision-rangegt), we learn that:

> When no `<revision-range>` is specified, it defaults to `HEAD`

So assuming there is a file called "example.txt", but no branch or tag called that, the following are all equivalent:

```
git log HEAD -- example.txt
git log HEAD example.txt
git log -- example.txt
git log example.txt
```

In all four cases, the `<revision-range>` is `HEAD`, and the `<path>` is `example.txt`.

---

In `git log`, [the meaning of `<path>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ltpathgt82308203) is:

> Show only commits that are enough to explain how the files that match the specified paths came to be.

In other words, while the `<revision-range>` decides what *branch* of history to look through, `<path>` decides what *commits inside that history* should be examined.

It also has another effect, which is crucial to understanding the next section: **when asked to show changes introduced by a commit, it only considers the changes to `<path>`**. For instance, if you run:

```
git log --oneline --name-status example.txt
```

You'll get something like this:

```
93f11d8429 Do the needful
M       example.txt
e4d79ce24c Make some changes
M       example.txt
2ce2aff50e Reformat all files to use non-breaking spaces lol
M       example.txt
```

To see all the *other* files in each commit, you have to pass [the `--full-diff` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---full-diff).

---

Now, back to `git show`. Although it doesn't give the same synopsis, it actually uses the same argument parsing, so for our same hypothetical repo, the following are equivalent:

```
git show HEAD -- example.txt
git show HEAD example.txt
git show -- example.txt
git show example.txt
```

So what does this actually do?

1. It processes the `<revision-range>` (`HEAD`) looking for a single commit; but because it's using the machinery from `git log`, what it actually gets is *a list with one item in*
2. It "simplifies" this list based on whether each commit "contributed to the history of `example.txt`" (the `<path>` argument).
3. As long as `example.txt` was actually changed in the current `HEAD` commit, it will still have one commit, and proceed with its display, starting with the summary of the commit.
4. It then prints a diff of the changes introduced by the commit, but **only the changes made to `<path>`**

You can demonstrate this is what's happening with a few variations:

- If you run `git show HEAD -- example-2.txt`, and `example-2.txt` exists, but *wasn't modified in the most recent commit*, you get an empty output: the revision is filtered out at step 2.
- The same is true if `example-2.txt` doesn't exist at all - it still processes step 1 successfully, so there's no error. Running `git show example-2.txt` would instead complain that it can't tell if `example-2.txt` was intended as a branch or a file, since it can't find either.
- If you run `git show --full-diff example.txt`, you'll get the same output as `git show HEAD`, *as long as `example.txt` was changed in the most recent commit*. The option changes step 4 to be "show all changes in the selected revision, regardless of `<path>`".

---

Finally, what about the format that *does* show the content?

```
git show HEAD:example.txt
git show :example.txt
```

In this case, `HEAD:example.txt` or `:example.txt` is a single argument, which can be interpreted as a `<revision-range>` according to [the general revision parser](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememmasterREADMEem):

> A suffix `:` followed by a path names the blob or tree at the given path in the tree-ish object named by the part before the colon.

For `git log`, this is valid but meaningless; but for `git show`, it leads to a completely different code path:

1. It looks at the `<revision-range>`, which is `HEAD:example.txt`, and decides what type it references.
2. Seeing that it references a blob, it decides to show *the content of that blob*.

Comment: @VonC You might be interested in my edit: I found the last piece of the puzzle of why the `<path>` causes the diff to be filtered, and why the whole commit can disappear - that's part of `git log`, too, it's just not often obvious.

Comment: Good catch. I suppose [the tests](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2807bd2c10606e590886543afe4e4f208dddd489/t/t7007-show.sh) can confirm this.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, @LeGEC, @IMSoP, and @VonC for the additional answers.
I have chosen LeGEC's for the bonus, and I'm also going to
provide a sort of a "distilled" answer here.  (This is an
informal answer; see the others for more precise details.)

The confusion is, how could

```
git show filename
```

*not* show you, like, that file?  Especially given that

```
git show revision:filename
```

*does* show you the file?  And the answer (as is so often the
case with git) is that you were thinking too narrowly, there's
actually more going on, and once you look at the bigger picture
things make more sense.

The first part of the answer is that `git show` is obviously
*not* just for showing files.  If you entered

```
git show revision
```

you would clearly want it to show you that revision, and showing
diffs is a great and appropriate way to show a revision.  So,
sometimes `git show` shows files, and sometimes it shows diffs,
and this shouldn't be surprising.
(And sometimes it shows other things, like trees.)

And then, the second part of the answer is that, like many git
commands, `git show` has the option to boil down some potentially
voluminous output to just the files you care about.
As a different example, with `git diff`, you can say

```
git diff revision
```

to show you diffs with respect to a certain revision, or you can say

```
git diff revision filename
```

to limit the diffs to just that filename.  Similarly, with `git show`, you can say

```
git show revision filename
```

to, again, limit the revision's diffs to just that filename.

But this is then the answer to the original question:
When you say

```
git show filename
```

it's a shortcut for

```
git show HEAD filename
```

and shows you just the diffs in the latest revision that apply to
the filename.

Or in other words, the surprising behavior of

```
git show filename
```

falls out of git's naming conventions, and the fact that there's
an implicit `HEAD` in there, making this an instance of the
`git show`-showing-revisions form, not
`git show`-showing-files.

Comment: `man git show`: “For commits it shows the log message and textual diff. […] For plain blobs, it shows the plain contents.” Dunno why this spawned a bounty hunt. :p

Comment: @Guildenstern Because when you type `git show filename` you don't realize (or don't understand why) you're asking for a commit; you assume you're asking for a plain blob.  Or should I say, "When you're a newbie and you type...".

Comment: I guess I’ve been burned so much (by my own mistakes) that I don’t question things as much. :)

Answer (score 2):

The OP mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57210267/why-does-git-show-filename-display-a-diff/76113837?noredirect=1#comment101013638_57212547):

> I think I got it:
>
> - `git show HEAD file` will compare HEAD with file, while
> - `git show HEAD:path/to/file` will operate only on the file and display its content.

[`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) works on "objects".

An object can be a commit (first case), a tag, a tree or a pain blob (second case)

The documentation confirms:

- For commits, it shows the log message and textual diff.
  It also presents the merge commit in a special format as produced by `git diff-tree --cc`.
- For plain blobs, it shows the plain contents.

[gitrevision](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememmasterREADMEem) documents that the most useful to address a blob is the `<rev>:<path>` syntax, e.g. `HEAD:README`, `master:./README`.

Comment: @IMSoP I agree. I was only repeating, as a starting point, what the OP mentioned initially in the comments.

Comment: As shown in my answer, it's not enough to look at the distinction between commits and blobs; we also need to understand what happens when you specify both a revision *and* a path, which is actually the case we're falling into, and has a rather specific meaning.

Comment: @IMSoP I have looked, and upvoted your answer.